# Not able to redirect parent window to another page from modaldialog child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My requirement is as mentioned below:

I have a modaldialog popup which I open using the following code:

```
window.showModalDialog('/test.jsp',window, 'center: yes; dialogHeight: 230px; dialogWidth: 550px; help: no;scroll:no;' );
```

I have a button in the modal dialog window which once clicked should close the popup and re-direct the parent window to login page.

I have tried the following:

```
var par = self.parent;
self.close();
par.location.replace("/login.jsp");
```

Now what is happening that modal dialog is getting closed but instead of redirecting the parent window to login page, a new window opens up and loads this page inside that.

Appreciated if  somebody could please give me some idea about the issue?

**Additional information:**

My parent window is in frameset. To access parent's reference from child, normally window.opener is used but here in this case, I get this as undefined. Not sure why.

**Answer:**

```
window.close()    
window.dialogArguments.location.href = "/login.jsp"
```

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
 window.opener.location = url;
window.close();
```

Comment: Thanks @ImadBakir I have tried this. This still opens the url in a new window instead of re-directing the parent window to the given url.

Comment: Thanks @ImadBakir I had tried this earlier also. window.opener comes as undefined so it's not able to set location property. That's why I had tried with self.parent before.

Comment: @Neeraj now I noticed that you're using `showModalDialog()`, window.opener.location doesn't work with it, why don't you use `window.open()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location.href = URL;
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.close()    
window.dialogArguments.location.href = "/login.jsp"
```